# PHP form sending mail producing blank output

Tags: php, html, forms, smtp

When I’m pressing submit I’m getting taken to a blank document taking me to the location `/mail.php`. Here’s the code.

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contactform" id="contactform">
    <table width="920" height="600" border="0" align="left">
        <tr>
          <th width="450" scope="row"><div align="left">
            <label for="firstname"></label>
            <span id="sprytextfield1">
            Full Name<br />
             <br />
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span> </div></th>
          <th width="450" scope="row"><label for="name"></label></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <span id="sprytextfield2"> E-Mail Address<br />
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></div></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left">
            <label for="contactno"></label>
            <span id="sprytextfield3"> Contact Number<br />
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="contactno" id="contactno" />
            <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><p align="left">Related Service</p>
            <p align="left">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Yes" id="service_0" />
              Alloy Wheels Repair</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="service1" value="Yes" id="service_1" />
              Leather & Cloth Repair</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="service2" value="Yes" id="service_2" />
              Paintless Dent Removal</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="service3" value="Yes" id="service_3" />
              Panel Repaint</label>
              <br />
          </p></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left">
          </div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><p align="left">
            <label for="number"></label>
            Address Area
          </p>
          <p align="left">
            <input type="text" name="area" id="area" />
        </p></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left">
            <label>
              Message<br />
              <br />
<textarea name="comments" id="message" cols="45" rows="6"></textarea>
            </label>
          </div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
          <th scope="row"><div align="left">
              <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send Message" />
          </div></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    require("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Your SMTP servers details

    $mail->IsSMTP();               // set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server or localhost
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "support@the(hidden)x.co.uk";  // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "!c(hidden)3"; // SMTP password
    // It should be same as that of the SMTP user

    $redirect_url = "http://www.the(hidden)x.co.uk/contactusthanks.html"; //Redirect URL after submit the form

    $mail->From = $mail->Username;  //Default From email same as smtp user
    $mail->FromName = "Display Name";

    $mail->AddAddress("(hidden)1966@gmail.com"); //Email address where you wish to receive/collect those emails.

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = $_POST['email'];
    $message = "Name of the requestor :".$_POST['name']." \r\n <br>Email Adrress :".$_POST['email']." \r\n <br> Phone number :".$_POST['contactno']." \r\n <br><br>Alloy Repair :".$_POST['service']." \r\n <br>Seat Repair :".$_POST['service1']." \r\n <br>Dent Repair :".$_POST['service2']." \r\n <br>Panel Repaint :".$_POST['service3']." \r\n <br>Customer Area :".$_POST['area']." \r\n <br><br> Message: ".$_POST['comments'];
    $mail->Body    = $message;

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }

    echo "Message has been sent";
    header("Location: $redirect_url");
}
?>
```

I’ve added the error checking at the beginning of my PHP script but I’m only getting a blank screen.

Comment: the purpose of output buffering is?

Comment: Check server error log. When setting things around error reporting inside PHP, they sometimes cause errors themselves. It is safer to put `php_flag display_errors on` into your Apache `.htaccess` because if this config option is refused, you get 500 HTTP error and you know what’s going on.

Comment: This is becaus you use ob_start() and store all output in an output buffer http://be2.php.net/ob_start

Comment: Good observation, @Dagon. Try deleting `ob_start();`.

Comment: change your error logging options at the php.ini level. If there's a syntax error in your script, it'll be killed **BEFORE** those `ini_set()` options can even get executed.

Comment: @palec I tried this but my actual .html became a 500 internal server error for some reason.

Comment: @Dagon I've deleted the line but still having no luck.

Comment: @MarcB I don't have access to the php.ini as i purchase my hosting

Comment: They should at least allow `php_value` in .htaccess, which is (almost) as good. If they don't, then I strongly suggest switching to a host that's more coder friendly. Without error reporting, you're debugging in the dark.

Comment: @MarcB I added "php_flag display_errors on" to my .htaccess and its broke every /html page i have lol

Comment: then they've disabled that option too, and you're hosed.

Comment: Try changing your `require` to `include`. Your `class.phpmailer.php` file may not exist. I know this is a painfully simple thing to check but it may save the rest of us a lot of headaches.

Comment: i'll have a chat with my hosters, what shall i ask for access too?

Comment: You need to look at your PHP and Apache/IIS Error Logs (or have your host provide them for you)... but please check on that `require`

Comment: Your host does have short tags enabled, right? Although you would still see something if not. Also, are you actually posting to the script and not just trying to open it in the browser? And you should remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` if you are not uploading any files.

Comment: @sjagr Still no luck :( the class.phpmailer.php is definatly in the public_html

Comment: Then your PHP/Apache Error Logs will give you a definite answer to your blank page problem. Maybe you should `var_dump($_POST)` at the very top of your `mail.php` file to make sure that the `$_POST` values are submitting correctly (or else you would be getting a blank page with no errors at all because your `if` condition hasn't been met)

Comment: @jeroen A very similar code im using with the same host for a different domain is working, and removing the enctype has gave us some information! http://pastebin.com/d9dRdy9p

Comment: service - service 3 are tick boxes...

Comment: If you leave those tick boxes unchecked, the `$_POST` values for them will not exist. You have to have a handler to check on a value of the checkbox, such as `!empty($_POST['service1']) ? 'Yes' : 'No'`

Comment: These are just warnings. You need to fix that, but it's not the reason the message does not get sent. You need to search for the `Mailer Error` (documentation, google, etc.).

Comment: @sjagr like this? \r\n <br><br>Alloy Repair :".!empty($_POST['service']) ? 'Yes' : 'No'." \r\n <br>Seat Repair :".!empty($_POST['service1']) ? 'Yes' : 'No'." \

Comment: Yes. Those are called ternary statements

Comment: Okay that worked and removed those errors - Now i'm left with Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: recipients_failedcarmedix1966@gmail.com

Comment: I'm thinkin this could be related to $mail->AddAddress("carmedix1966@gmail.com");

Comment: @sjagr Conditional operator, ternary operator. It is not a statement, it is an expression.

Comment: My working PHP script has two entries heres the code $mail->AddAddress("enquiries@chapnology.co.uk", "chapnolo");

I wasn't sure what the second entry was so i removed it

Comment: @Metexora Completely abandoned the question? Is the conclusion I came to in the comments below my answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a big struggle, all our headaches turned out to actually be something quite simple....

```
"Michael B: the domain entry was missing on server in below file
Michael B: /etc/localdomains
Michael B: I have added the entry"
```

Thank-you everyone for your assistance much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

As discussed in comments below your question, your hosting does not support changing PHP configuration changes regarding errors.

Also you erroneously enabled output buffering and you never flush the buffer. It may get flushed automatically on script termination, but I did not manage to find it in documentation. It is safer to switch output buffering off when you don’t need it.

The solution should be deletion of these three lines:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();
```

Comment: How would hiding the errors solve the problem? Also, the output buffer probably gets flushed to the browser at script termination: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lfihze

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have deleted these three lines and it is still only taking me to a blank page. Also these three lines of code are on my other domain and the form works fine. This one is a headahce!

Comment: @Metexora The first two errors say that you did not provide `$_POST['service1']` and `$_POST['service3']` values. Checkboxes do not send anything when not checked. The last one reveals your address, obviously set in `$mail->AddAddress("(hidden)1966@gmail.com");`. I’m puzzled with this one.

Comment: @Metexora Maybe you should include `class.smtp.php` too. [PHPMailer README](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md) says that you need it for SMTP. And you use SMTP (`$mail->IsSMTP()`).

Comment: The error occurs at [`class.phpmailer.php` line 1227](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L1227). It should reference the item at [line 1372](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L1372). It seems you should call `$mail->setLanguage();` which sets English by default.

Comment: i added the $mail->setLanguage(); in my php and now i get this error http://pastebin.com/NZMRCJg5

Comment: @Metexora You have a rather dated version of PHPMailer. I am surprised that it more-or-less works today. Please upgrade and see if it solves your problem. If you insist on using your old PHPMailer, try using `$mail->setLanguage('en');`, but I will not participate on debugging such an ancient code anymore.